# Avoiding Global Variables

Tags: r, global-variables

I'd like to make a basic profiling tool that collects time stamps and produces run times with a note.  The only problem is I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this without using global variables.  What's the "correct" way to implement the functionality I'm trying to achieve?  If R already has this functionality built in, that's awesome, but what I'm really trying to figure out here is how to avoid using global variables and write more robust code.

```
timeStamps = c()
runTimes = list()

appendRunTimes <- function(note) {
  if(length(timeStamps) < 1) {
    timeStamps <<- Sys.time()
  }
  else {
    timeStamps <<- c(timeStamps, Sys.time())
    diff <- timeStamps[length(timeStamps) ] - timeStamps[length(timeStamps) - 1]
    runTimes <<- c(runTimes,  format(diff))
    names(runTimes)[length(runTimes)] <<-  note
  }

}


appendRunTimes('start')
Sys.sleep(4)
appendRunTimes('test')
```

Comment: I'd look at the code of `system.time` for ideas.. or use it!  You can also look at the code for some of the benchmarking packages (`microbenchmark` for example).

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions, see "Introduction to R" (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) section 10.7, page 50 (2.15.2 revision).

Answer (score 8):

Here's your example rewritten using closures:

```
RTmonitor <- local({
  timeStamps = c()
  runTimes = list()

  list(
    appendRunTimes=function(note) {
      if(length(timeStamps) < 1) {
        timeStamps <<- Sys.time()
      }
      else {
        timeStamps <<- c(timeStamps, Sys.time())
        diff <- timeStamps[length(timeStamps) ] - timeStamps[length(timeStamps) - 1]
        runTimes <<- c(runTimes,  format(diff))
        names(runTimes)[length(runTimes)] <<-  note
      }
    },
    viewRunTimes=function() {
      return(list(timeStamps=timeStamps,runTimes=runTimes))
    })
})


> RTmonitor$appendRunTimes("start")
> RTmonitor$appendRunTimes("test")
> RTmonitor$viewRunTimes()
$timeStamps
[1] "2013-01-04 18:39:12 EST" "2013-01-04 18:39:21 EST"

$runTimes
$runTimes$test
[1] "8.855587 secs"
```

Observe that the values are stored inside the closure, not in the global environment:

```
> timeStamps
Error: object 'timeStamps' not found
> runTimes
Error: object 'runTimes' not found
> RTmonitor$timeStamps
NULL
> RTmonitor$runTimes
NULL
```

More reading on closures and avoiding globals:

- [Closures as solution to data merging idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797273/closures-as-solution-to-data-merging-idiom)
- [How does local() differ from other approaches to closure in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901916/how-does-local-differ-from-other-approaches-to-closure-in-r)
- [Why is using `<<-` frowned upon and how can I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851655/why-is-using-frowned-upon-and-how-can-i-avoid-it)
- [Examples of the perils of globals in R and Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526322/examples-of-the-perils-of-globals-in-r-and-stata)

Comment: You're only one step from R.oo or possibly using ReferenceClasses here, aren't you?

Comment: @Spacedman Want to post a R.oo or RefClass solution? :-)  I'd be interested in seeing what others come up with.

Answer (score 4):

Here's now to do this using ReferenceClasses:

```
RTmonitor = setRefClass("RTmonitor",
  fields=list(
    timeStamps="POSIXct",
    runTimes = "list"
    ),
  methods=list(
    appendRunTimes=function(note){
      if(length(timeStamps)==0){
        timeStamps <<- Sys.time()
      }else{
        timeStamps <<- c(timeStamps, Sys.time())
        diff <- timeStamps[length(timeStamps) ] - timeStamps[length(timeStamps) - 1]
        runTimes <<- c(runTimes,  format(diff))
        names(runTimes)[length(runTimes)] <<-  note
      }
    }
    )
  )
```

Now you've defined a class, instantiate an object and use it:

```
> r = RTmonitor$new()
> r$appendRunTimes("start")
> r$appendRunTimes("test")
> r
Reference class object of class "RTmonitor"
Field "timeStamps":
[1] "2013-01-05 14:52:25 GMT" "2013-01-05 14:52:31 GMT"
Field "runTimes":
$test
[1] "5.175815 secs"
```

Very similar to the closure approach, but more formalised. I had to define the `timeStamps` field as `POSIXct`, for example. You can also create multiple `RTmonitor` objects this way and they work independently - you'd have to write a closure constructor that wrapped the closure to do that.