# What are elegant ways of in-order splicing things (vectors and dataframes) in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have three vectors **a.1**, **a.2**, **a.3** -- they could hold arbitrary values (meaning the values would not necessarily be sorted)

```
> a.1 <- seq(1,15,3)
> a.2 <- seq(15,2,-3)
> a.3 <- seq(2,15,3)
> a.1
[1]  1  4  7 10 13
> a.2
[1] 15 12  9  6  3
> a.3
[1]  2  5  8 11 14
```

Now I want to produce a new vector **C** where I take all elements of **a** except elements at indices **2**, **3**, **5** and only elements at indices **2**, **3** from vector **a.2** and element at index **5** from **a.3**; combine them in order

One way I know how to do this is:

```
> C <- a.1
> C[c(2,3)] <- a.2[c(2,3)]
> C[5] <- a.3[5]
> C
[1]  1 12  9 10 14
```

I wonder if there are are **better** ways of doing this -- better may include:

1. More elegant
2. Extendable to say splices from multiple elements
3. More Terse (syntax wise)

**Notes**

1. One of the answer authors has suggested using replace -- I wonder if replace can be used in multiway splices
2. Also note the vales in the source or target vector need not be sorted
3. It would be great if the same solution can be used (barring some minor modifications) on both vectors and dataframes

Comment: Maybe `replace`? `replace(a, s, b[s])`.

Comment: @Psidom thanks ... ... good .... do you think we could extend this to multi-way splices

Comment: You need to be more specific about the `multi-way splices`.

Comment: @Psidom -- let me update the question with multiway splices

Comment: @user1172468 - but what do you mean by multiway splices? Joining three vectors? How do you see that working?

Comment: @thelatemail -- just updated the question -- please take a look and see if it makes sense -- many thanks

Comment: @Psidom hi there -- modified the question

Comment: @user1172468 did one of our answers solve your problem?

Comment: @AidanGawronski -- they did -- however those were known to me -- I'm looking for something more elegant.

Comment: @user1172468 if they were known to you why did you use an inferior version in the first place ... not only that both answers are 2) Extendable & 3) More Terse

Comment: @AidanGawronski -- those are answers I could have constructed via mapply or say a loop -- the replace was interesting (had forgotten that)

Comment: @user1172468 you are literally a bad person

Comment: @AidanGawronski -- lol -- seriously -- tell me more

Answer (score 4):

In this case, I'd just use a boring old loop and overwrite the corresponding indexes from each object:

```
multchange <- function(x, repl, idx) {
  for (i in seq_along(repl)) {
    x[idx[[i]]] <- repl[[i]][idx[[i]]]
  }
  x
}

df_list <- list(a.2, a.3)
cool_list <- list(c(2,3), 5)
multchange(a.1, df_list, cool_list)
#[1]  1 12  9 10 14
```

And no, using a loop is not slower on a large dataset:

```
samp <- rep(1:2,each=1000000)
df_list <- list(a.2, a.3)[samp]
cool_list <- list(c(2,3), 5)[samp]

system.time({
  multchange(a.1, df_list, cool_list)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   4.24    0.00    4.25 

c <- a.1
system.time({
  mapply(function(X, Y) { c[Y] <<- X[Y] }, X=df_list, Y=cool_list)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   7.46    0.00    7.49
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df_list <- list(a.2, a.3)
cool_list <- list(c(2,3), 5)
c <- a.1
mapply(function(X, Y) { c[Y] <<- X[Y] }, X=df_list, Y=cool_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- but this assumes the vectors are sorted -- let me clarify the question

Comment: Hi, clarified the question a bit -- see if it makes sense

Comment: @user1172468 Your example is broken, and it is very unclear what your expected output is.

Comment: The above answer will extend to any number of vectors and "splices".

Comment: I'd avoid using `<<-` - if you're going to do that, just wrap a loop that does `<-` multiple times in a function and return the changed `c`. It will be far more predictable.

Comment: Everyone is so afraid of using the super assignment operator ... I like it!

Comment: @AidanGawronski - it's not about being afraid, it's that it can give unintended results if the function is called inside a different function. E.g. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851655/why-is-using-frowned-upon-and-how-can-i-avoid-it/9851794 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166207/avoiding-global-variables/14166812 for example.

Comment: Still doesn't seem like an unexpected result. Basically the fear is people use it without understanding it.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer by the way if you're wondering.